# ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis in replace

Tags: sql, oracle

Following SQL

```
select replace (IBSECM.IBSECM582CTEXT1SHRT, 'Curtina', 'Curtine') from table IBSECM;
```

is giving following error:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis
```

What am I missing?

I am using an Oracle DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove `table` keyword:

```
select replace (IBSECM.IBSECM582CTEXT1SHRT, 'Curtina', 'Curtine') from IBSECM;
```